# Take two sets 'A' and 'B' , how to create a set C= A minus B in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, set, operation

Consider I have two sets 'A' and 'B', how do I create a set C= A minus B in pandas. Here A and B are dataframes. A is a dataframe containing First name and Last name as multiindex. B has integers as index. First name and Last name are columns in B.

I tried by converting multindex of A to column of A by A['index']=A.index and later tried to merge B and A.But it is not working.

A:

[image: csv for A.csv]

B:

[image: csv for B.csv]

The columns of B (f_Name and l_name) are multiindex of A.

I want all rows in A for which f_name and l_name does not exist in B as output. I have tried following code:

```
A['index']=A.index

my_df=pd.merge(A,B,left_on=['F_name','L_name'],right_index=True,how='left'] 

ans_df=A[~A.index.isin(my_df.index)]
```

but the len(and_df) is same as len(A) which is not correct. The length of ans_df should be less than that of A as few f_name and l_name exist in B.

Comment: Please show us the code from what you have tried so far and specify what exactly "is not working".

Comment: hi @gus27, can you please help...i have added the code in question

Comment: why does this have to be like pulling theeth. YOu have posted your code but have you bothered to format it? no.

Comment: Mahesh, in the question editor there's a help button (indicated by a ?). Here you can see how to format `code`.

Comment: @Mahesh Please insert how you initialize A and don't forget to specify what exactly "is not working".

Comment: @gus27..yes i'll do that..please wait

Comment: check out the `pandas.Index.difference()` and `pandas.DataFrame.diff()` functions. The documentation is quite straightforward, but without more information I cannot see how to solve your specific problem

Comment: @Celebrian..thank you...i'll check

Comment: change how='left' to how='inner' if you are doing how='left', you are basically selecting all the rows of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the dataframes ***A*** and ***B***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A
               Age  Gender
F_name  L_name      
Josh    Crammer 25  M
John    Smith   29  M
Mellisa Simpson 32  F
Ahemed  Khan    26  M
Frank   J       25  M
Charles Brown   26  M
William Gibson  26  M

B
    F_name  L_name
0   Josh    Crammer
2   Mellisa Simpson
4   Frank   J
5   Charles Brown
6   William Gibson
```

What we can do is reset the index of A and create columns in place like this.

```
A.reset_index(level=A.index.names, inplace=True)
A
    F_name  L_name  Age Gender
0   Josh    Crammer 25  M
1   John    Smith   29  M
2   Mellisa Simpson 32  F
3   Ahemed  Khan    26  M
4   Frank   J       25  M
5   Charles Brown   26  M
6   William Gibson  26  M
```

All that needs to be done now is to add a not in condition to fetch the rows we require:

```
A[~((A.F_name.isin(B.F_name)) & (A.L_name.isin(B.L_name)))]
    F_name  L_name  Age Gender
1   John    Smith   29  M
3   Ahemed  Khan    26  M
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution using fake column

*Disclaimer: Below you can find example of the "fake column" approach which may not be suitable for huge dataframes with many matching columns of complex types. Besides, I prefer to work with simple indexes and put as many data into columns rather than in indexes.*

So, lets create two datasets: A will contain few random Family Guy characters, and B will contain few Family Guy family members. Hope you are familiar with this awesome TV series! :)

```
# Create a DF A with some Quahog Family guy citizens (with multiindex)
multiindexA = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([["Peter","Griffin"],["Glenn","Quagmire"],["Joe","Swanson"],["Cleveland","Brown"],["Brian","Griffin"],["Stewie","Griffin"],["Lois","Griffin"]],names=["Name","Surname"])
A=pd.DataFrame([40,35,38,45,8,2,35],index=multiindexA, columns=["Age"])
print A

                    Age
Name      Surname      
Peter     Griffin    40
Glenn     Quagmire   35
Joe       Swanson    38
Cleveland Brown      45
Brian     Griffin     8
Stewie    Griffin     2
Lois      Griffin    35


# Create a DF B with some Family guy inner family members (with simple simple index)
B = pd.DataFrame(data=[["Peter","Griffin",40],["Lois","Griffin",35],["Brian","Griffin",8],["Stewie","Griffin",2]], columns=["Name","Surname","Age"])
print B

     Name  Surname  Age
0   Peter  Griffin   40
1    Lois  Griffin   35
2   Brian  Griffin    8
3  Stewie  Griffin    2
```

Let's find the Family Guy characters that are not members of the Griffin family. Firstly, we will use `reset_index` to normalize dataframes into the same structure since this is going to make our lives much easier:

```
# Reset index to move multiindex into columns in order to normalize dataframes
A = A.reset_index()
print A

        Name   Surname  Age
0      Peter   Griffin   40
1      Glenn  Quagmire   35
2        Joe   Swanson   38
3  Cleveland     Brown   45
4      Brian   Griffin    8
5     Stewie   Griffin    2
6       Lois   Griffin   35
```

Since you are matching on two (or even more columns), one (possibly dirty and memory wasting) solution might be **creating a fake index column** by combining interesting columns into one with `.apply(lambda x: ...)` function. Keep in mind that you have to convert any non-string fields into strings with `.astype(str)`.:

```
#Create a new dummy column by merging all matching columns into one (in both dataframes!)
A["fake_index_col"]=A[["Name","Surname","Age"]].astype(str).apply(lambda x: "".join(x),axis=1)
B["fake_index_col"]=B[["Name","Surname","Age"]].astype(str).apply(lambda x: "".join(x),axis=1)
```

This will add a dummy column to both of the dataframe, where all the matching data will be compressed into one single field.

```
        Name   Surname  Age    fake_index_col
0      Peter   Griffin   40    PeterGriffin40
1      Glenn  Quagmire   35   GlennQuagmire35
2        Joe   Swanson   38      JoeSwanson38
3  Cleveland     Brown   45  ClevelandBrown45
4      Brian   Griffin    8     BrianGriffin8
5     Stewie   Griffin    2    StewieGriffin2
6       Lois   Griffin   35     LoisGriffin35
```

This will allow you to easily apply the inverse of `isin` function to find the citizens of Quahog that are not Griffins. Finally delete the fake column and/or recreate multiindex to preserve the initial state of the dataframe.

```
C = A[~A["fake_index_col"].isin(B["fake_index_col"])]
del C["fake_index_col"]
print C



        Name   Surname  Age
1      Glenn  Quagmire   35
2        Joe   Swanson   38
3  Cleveland     Brown   45
```